# 404 ( No Such Object ) MediaLink not working for images after transferring bucket from one project to another

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I had a bucket to store image for **public access** , now I **transferred** the bucket to **another project** and gave it **public access**. However the **mediaLink** for images which were generated ( **before transfer** ) and saved in my personal database is broken now.

MediaLink :-

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/bucket/o/61249d20709f5f61ec6d8374%2Fimage_picker4230948959955182432.jpg?generation=1630414474820126&alt=media
```

Error I am getting :-

```
No such object: bucket/61249d20709f5f61ec6d8374/image_picker4230948959955182432.jpg
```

Comment: Is your bucket named `bucket`? Or are you replacing it as a placeholder to ask the question?

Comment: It's not real name. Yes it's placeholder

Comment: What's that link? From where did you generate it?

Comment: It is the mediaLink generated when uploaded file in Spring Boot using Google Storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you “transfer” a bucket to another project what you are doing is actually [a copy](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets#:%7E:text=If%20you%20have%20data%20in%20your%20old%20bucket%2C%20create%20a%20new%20bucket%20with%20the%20desired%20name%2C%20location%2C%20and/or%20project%2C%20copy%20data%20from%20the%20old%20bucket%20to%20the%20new%20bucket%2C%20and%20delete%20the%20old%20bucket%20and%20its%20contents), meaning you are uploading the objects again to the bucket in the new project, and not moving the already uploaded files from the first project.

This process causes the mediaLink to change as [each object generates new metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#fixed) everytime time it’s uploaded. If you try to reuse the same mediaLinks you had from the previous bucket, you will get that error.

To fix this you will need to get the new mediaLinks for the objects in the new bucket.

Comment: Ok. Any workaround to reuse the previous generated media link ?

Comment: If you have deleted the files from the old bucket, then the objects those medialinks are  referencing to do not exist anymore so you cannot reuse them